# Apple App Store submission review time vs update time

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I've released an app to the App Store, it's been waiting for review for about 9 days.

Upon running my own dev version I've realised I'd left a critical part out. Would it be worth waiting for release and then pushing an update or remove it and resubmit?

Will the update be processed faster than a resubmission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updates are generally processed faster than the first submission of an app for review, but not *drastically* faster. It's usually around a day shorter (5 days) compared with the average 6 or 7 days for a first submission.

Note that iOS 8 has caused an increase in submissions and a [consequential increase in review times](http://appreviewtimes.com); Apple may be prioritising updates more to make apps compatible with iOS 8.

Comment: In my experience this is not true. I've submitted a number of new apps and updates, and both in the last 6 months have taken around 10-14 days

Answer (score 1):

Check out this resource http://appreviewtimes.com/ . Very handy but it doesn't distinguish between first submissions and updates unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you check Apple's developer site they list the percent of new and updates approved in 5 business days or less. I'm not sure how accurate this is because in my experience it usually takes 7-10 days to get either a new app or update approved and far longer if you get rejected.

Apple's review claims link: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/

Actual times from statistical sample: http://appreviewtimes.com/

Between the two there is a big discrepancy, or I am just really unlucky as it takes about 10 days (7 business days or so) for me to get updates through for You Doodle.

Comment: Do you have a link for that?

Comment: @HaemEternal Added links